# how to write python code in the zope page template

Tags: plone, zope, template-tal, zpt

I am very new to Zope and Plone. I am trying to write python code in the index_html page. I have the list of objects of type person, now I want to reorder them. So, what I had before was:

```
<ul tal:define="persons python: context.portal_catalog(portal_type='Person');">
<tal:listing repeat="p persons">
```

Now I have this python code before the `<tal:listing`...

```
<?python
  order=[0,2,1]
  persons = [persons[i] for i in order]
?>
```

But somehow the order of the person remains the same. Also, I also don't like this way of writing python code in the view. Is there any way I could use this code for changing the order of the list?

Comment: The `<? ?>` syntax is not supported at all by Zope page templates. Where did you find that syntax?

Comment: I found it from www.mail-archive.com/zpt@zope.org/msg00046.html . I realized that if i change the persons to new_persons in python code and try to access it in <tal:listing repeat "p new_persons">, it doesn't know about this new_person! I think I should write this python code somewhere else. Currently I am writing it in the browser template! Where should I write this code and how do I access this code on the template?

Comment: Ah, that is someone *asking* for a feature, not describing what ZPT can do. :-)

Comment: but is there anyway i can change the order of the list person?

Comment: I've already posted an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zope pagetemplates do not support a `<? ?>` syntax at all.

However, you can loop over your python list in the `tal:repeat` just fine:

```xml
<ul tal:define="persons python: context.portal_catalog(portal_type='Person');">
    <tal:listing repeat="i python:[0, 2, 1]">
        <li tal:define="p python:persons[i]" tal:content="p/name">Person name</li>
    </tal:listing>
</ul>
```

I suspect however, that you want to let the portal_catalog do the sorting instead, using the `sort_on` parameter (see the [Plone KB article on the catalog](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/indexing-and-searching/querying-the-catalog/)):

```xml
<ul tal:define="persons python: context.portal_catalog(portal_type='Person', sort_on='sortable_title');">
    <tal:listing repeat="p persons">
        <li tal:content="p/name">Person name</li>
    </tal:listing>
</ul>
```

If you want to do anything more complex, use a [browser view](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/archetypes/appendix-practicals/b-org-creating-content-types-the-plone-2.5-way/zope-3-views) to do the list massaging for you.

Comment: But is it a good practice to handle logic in the view? And where do you define the "sortable_title" in the class Person.py?

Comment: It's better to push logic to views, but small amounts of ordering and such can be handled in the template.

Comment: 'sortable_title' is an index defined by Plone in the portal_catalog, you have nothing to declare for using it.

Comment: But when I use the same thing and run it it gives me error saying that "sortable_title" is not defined anywhere!

Comment: Sounds like you are forgetting to put quotes around `sortable_table`; it is a python string, not a variable name.